# Forbidden access to theme folder subdirectory in Yii

Tags: php, yii, webfonts

I am trying to create a theme in Yii framework but I have a problem to load fonts from the theme folder. here is my code in the head of my html:

```
<style>
/* Fix font-awesome path  */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    src: url('<?php echo $fontPath ?>awesome-webfont.eot")?v=3.1.1');
    src: url('<?php echo $fontPath ?>fontawesome-webfont.eot")?#iefix&v=3.1.1') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('<?php echo $fontPath ?>fontawesome-webfont.woff")?v=3.1.1') format('woff'),
    url('<?php echo $fontPath ?>fontawesome-webfont.ttf")?v=3.1.1') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
</style>
```

Where

```
$fontPath = Yii::app()->theme->baseurl . '/font/';
```

I get 403 (Forbidden) error in my html while loading the page. Is there any other way I can load the fonts other than changing the fonts location and moving them to another folder?

Comment: where is your font folder ?? is this in theme folder?

Comment: theme/[my_theme_name]/font

Comment: It's supposed to be in themes/[me_theme_name]/font (not 'theme')